# What does JSON stringify do in react native

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native application development.I have some confusion regarding JSON.stringify method.Here is my code.

```
fetch('http://link.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: formData

    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            loading_status: false
        })

        if (!responseJson.error) {

            var id = responseJson.result.id
            var roles_id = responseJson.result.roles_id

            AsyncStorage.multiSet([
                ['user_id', id.toString()],
                ['roles_id', roles_id.toString()],

            ]);

        } else {
            //error

        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);

        Platform.OS === 'android' ? ToastAndroid.show("Connection Error !", ToastAndroid.SHORT) : Alert.alert("Connection Error !")

        return;
    });
```

But main problem arises when i started to make build for that.What i saw is that value which is not in string produces error while writing or reading data from async storage.
It gives me error in ios build something like.
`NSnull cannot be converted into NSString`
So i changed my code to something like this

```
 if (!responseJson.error) {

    var id = JSON.stringify(responseJson.result.id)
    var roles_id = JSON.stringify(responseJson.result.roles_id)

    AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        ['user_id', id],
        ['roles_id', roles_id],

    ]);
}
```

Now this works fine in ios build.So my doubt is that how can i parse a json or is there any standart way to parse json in react native so that i did not face problem which is faced while making ios build for react native.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() is used to convert JSON into a string. To parse the string data JSON.parse() is used.

Comment: can u elaborate ? i mean is there any standard way to parse json in react native.I need help with some code

Comment: yes bro. {error:true,message:'asd',results:[]} This is format of a json response

Comment: JSON.parse() is sufficient there is as such no specific way in react native

Comment: what to do after json.parse?

Comment: i mean whats the difference between response.json() and json.parse()

Comment: This method response.json() reads the remote data and parses it as JSON. JSON.parse() parses the stingified json to json.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it's not clear where the null is coming from, but you can take a look at adding a `replacer` function into the `JSON.stringify` call.  See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for details.  Something like:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (value === null) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return value;
 }
 ...
 let result = JSON.stringify(responseJSON.result, replacer);
```

This allows you to modify the stringify results as needed.